# Rails paperclip gem image display error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

Hi All Iam using the paperclip gem from https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip and the rails cast from http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip.

I am having trouble getting my images to display after using:

```
<%= image_tag @post.photo.url %>
```

on my post show page 'show.html.erb'. The broken link image is displayed instead of the image itself.

It has the following in the HTML for the image:

Has anyone got any tips to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

///////////////////
Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, presence: true,
  length: { minimum: 5}
  has_attached_file :photo
end
```

///////////
Schema

```
create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.date     "date"
    t.time     "time"
    t.text     "description"
    t.text     "dresscode"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "image"
    t.string   "photo_file_name"
    t.string   "photo_content_type"
    t.integer  "photo_file_size"
    t.datetime "photo_updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: You can specify the image path and url in your model. Check this out in the github readme.

Comment: Pretty hard to debug this without seeing it in action. Any chance you can show us more code than just one line? Like the model and the database schema for that table?

Comment: Sorry I have updated this question.

Comment: Are you sure, you are having image URL in table, check `photo_file_name` in `Database`.

Comment: Yes I have the photo_file_name field in my schema file

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Rails 3.2, why not try adding this to your Post model:

```
attr_accessible :photo
```

Comment: No luck when testing this its like its not saving the image

Answer (score 0):

I think you've added options to photo attribute i model after uploading the photo, try to reupload the photo once!

Comment: Please could you re-explain this RSB thanks, I tried this and it didnt work, it has the following in the HTML for the image: <img alt="Missing" src="/photos/original/missing.png">

Comment: have you tried uploading images with different extensions?! (jpg, gif, ..)